# Extracting number in parenthesis in R using regex

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract the 22 from below:

```
"Feb22 19  (22) 100  (Weeklys) "
```

I have tried the below but with no luck. Any suggestions?

```
grep("\\(.*\\)", "Feb22 19  (22) 100  (Weeklys) ", value= TRUE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using `sub` with a capture group:

```
x <- "Feb22 19  (22) 100  (Weeklys) "
sub(".*\\((\\d+)\\).*", "\\1", x)

[1] "22"
```

The above pattern can be explained as:

```
.*     consume anything, up until the last
\(     literal open parenthesis, which is then followed by
(\d+)  one or more digits (which are captured)
\)     followed by a closing parenthesis
.*     followed by anything
```

The replacement is `\\1`, which is the number captured in the pattern.  Note that should the input *not* contain a number in parentheses, the above call to `sub` would actually return the original input string.  If you don't like this behavior, then you will have to do more work.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use:

```
    string<-"Feb22 19 (22) 100 (Weeklys) "
    unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(string,"\\d{1,}(?=\\))"))
    #[1] "22"
```

I was recently advised to use `simplify` although I find `unlist`'s output better.

Using `stringr::str_extract_all(string,"\\d{1,}(?=\\))",simplify=TRUE)`

```
    [,1]
[1,] "22"
```